# Una BD se crea a partir de un modelo relacional?

Tags: base-de-datos, mysql-workbench

Tenemos un aplicativo de escritorio y necesitamos hacer la BD, en las relaciones de muchos a muchos que el diagrama presenta, según el modelo relacional hay que hacer una nueva tabla que incluyan las llaves primarias de las entidades implicadas. Al hacer la BD en mysql es necesario incluir la tabla de sale las relaciones de muchos a muchos?

Comment: no se entiende mucho la pregunta. si no creas esa tabla, donde guardarias las relaciones en la base de datos?

Comment: por su puesto que es estrictamente necesario, sobre todo si pretendes exportar tu modelo ERR desde workbench a mysql. 

Saludos.